# chmod 777 is not changing the permissions to 777

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to change the permissions of temp_dir to 777.  Why are these commands not accomplishing that?  I'm using Linux by the way.

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ chmod 777 /mnt/disks/temp_dir
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ stat -c "%a %n" temp_dir
755 temp_dir
```

I also tried the verbose switch

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ chmod -v 777 /mnt/disks/temp_dir
mode of '/mnt/disks/temp_dir' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ stat -c "%a %n" temp_dir
755 temp_dir
```

I also don't understand why I can't use `sudo`

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks/temp_dir$ sudo chmod 777 fix_mistakes
chmod: cannot access 'fix_mistakes': Permission denied
```

Even when I log in as root user

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks/temp_dir$ sudo -i
root@kfoley76:~# sudo chmod 777 /mnt/disks/temp_dir
chmod: cannot access '/mnt/disks/temp_dir': Permission denied
```

I should also add that this bug must have something to do with the fact that the directory in question is a gcsfuse mounted disk, available from gcloud.  Other attempts to change permissions worked fine:

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:~$ mkdir hey
kylefoley@kfoley76:~$ stat -c "%a %n" hey
755 hey
kylefoley@kfoley76:~$ chmod 777 hey
kylefoley@kfoley76:~$ stat -c "%a %n" hey
777 hey
```

Comment: Please post what `umask` outputs.

Comment: deduction1 on /mnt/disks/temp_dir type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1001,default_permissions)

Comment: that was the umask output

Comment: Note that `chmod 777` should *never* be run. The number of circumstances where world writability does not seriously damage the UNIX security model (particularly given existence of accounts like `nobody` used to sandbox execution of untrusted code) are very few.

Comment: well, i have such a difficult time determining whether or not i am the owner of the file.

Answer (score 15):

gcsfuse sets file and directory permissions when mounting.  Specifically, the options are:

- `file_mode` – Permission bits for files, in octal
- `dir_mode` – Permissions bits for directories, in octal

<sup><sub>Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/e0a0e0826897b09581c24065fb6a92912ee79d03/flags.go#L78</sub></sup>

If you do not specify the options, the defaults are `dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644`.

<sup><sub>Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/e0a0e0826897b09581c24065fb6a92912ee79d03/flags.go#L51</sub></sup>

These options apply to all files and directories in the mount.  This FUSE file system does not have the capability of changing permissions for specific files or directories, which is why `chmod` does nothing.

---

Furthermore, gcsfuse has additional access restrictions that limit access to the user who mounted the file system.  Details:

> As a security measure, fuse itself restricts file system access to the
>   user who mounted the file system (cf. [fuse.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a33f32244/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt#L253-L300)). For this reason,
>   gcsfuse by default shows all files as owned by the invoking user.
>   Therefore you should invoke gcsfuse as the user that will be using the
>   file system, not as root.
>
> If you know what you are doing, you can override these behaviors with
>   the [`allow_other`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a33f32244/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt#L100-L105) mount option supported by fuse and with the `--uid` and
>   `--gid` flags supported by gcsfuse. Be careful, this may have security implications!

<sub><sup>Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/d25be2491879e3745c3ed3d8e816774defc1cc5c/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions</sup></sub>

This is why you aren't able to access the mount from another user.  To allow other users to access the mount, specify `allow_other` in your mount options.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way: I had to go to Cloud API Access Scopes and verify under the VM configuration that it has read write or full access for storage. This involved pressing edit on the gcloud console which lists my instances.  At the bottom of the page, there was the limitation for storage which I changed to 'full'.  That did it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer (or another), to help others who read this question in future. Note that on some sites you may have to wait before accepting an answer.,